# How to use a loop to add every positive integer less than N to sum?

Tags: javascript, loops

guys i know this is amateur javascript stuff but can someone please help me solve this challenge:

```
// You are given one numeric variable:
var n = 25;

// Its value may change when you submit.
// DO NOT EDIT CODE ABOVE THIS LINE.
// =================================

// Your Challenge:
// 1. Declare a new variable named "sum" and initialize it to 0.
// Be sure to use the "var" keyword.
// 2. Use a for loop to add every positive integer less than n to sum.
// 3. Come up with a solution that works for all values of n.

// Your code:


var sum = 0;
var n = 25;

for (n = 25; sum <= n; sum++) {
    alert(n);
    console.log(n);
    n + sum;
}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Are my conditions wrong?
My operators?

I have a gut feeling it's my actual block of code that's off but can't figure out what exactly to write in order to come up with a solution. Thanks

Comment: first of all you are re declaring n . Second, your for loop is wrong. Second, your condition sum<=n will never fail causing your code to go into infinite loop.

Comment: It looks like you're using SO to avoid doing your homework ;)

Answer (score 0):

Start wit n = 25. Check it while being higher than 0. Decrement n (n--). Add current n to sum (sum += n).

```
var n = 25;
var sum = 0;
for(; n > 0; n--)
{
   sum += n;
}
document.write(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// You are given one numeric variable:
var n = 25;

// Its value may change when you submit.
// DO NOT EDIT CODE ABOVE THIS LINE.
// =================================

// Your Challenge:
// 1. Declare a new variable named "sum" and initialize it to 0.
// Be sure to use the "var" keyword.
// 2. Use a for loop to add every positive integer less than n to sum.
// 3. Come up with a solution that works for all values of n.

// Your code:


var sum = 0;
// don not declare n again
    // loop through num values add it to sum
    for (var n = 25; sum < n; n--) {
    //check value is positive
        if (sum >= 0) {
            sum++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The check `if (sum >= 0)` is unnecessary as it will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this function to get the Sum

```
var getSum = function(limit){
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i=1; i<limit; i++){
     sum+= i;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Then you could do something like `console.log(getSum(25));` to get the desired output.

Basically the function runs a for loop from 1 (since only positive integers) to n-1 (excluding n) and adds the current iterator to sum, which was initialized to `0`